# Php Convert a Mac Unix Timestamp to Y-m-d G:i:s

Tags: php, unix, timestamp

I am trying to convert a Mac UNIX timestamp to date time.

3448286095 should be converted to 2013-04-09 00:14:55.

I tried:

echo date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime(3448286095));

The output is not correct.

UNIX Timestamp: seconds since Jan 1, 1970.
Mac Timestamp: seconds since Jan 1, 1904.

Comment: see http://3v4l.org/Vqr7d

Comment: Thanks, the date this prints out is one day early so I added a day to the start date. 1904-01-02

Comment: Don't do that. Rather make sure your timezone is set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, another stupid Mac Timestamp-only approach:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$date = new DateTime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', 3448286095));
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P66Y'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

which output:

```
2013-04-09 17:14:55
```

Comment: No, It's called interval spec. Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

Comment: Ahh I see, you have to add 66 years to convert it.